# Making a calculator that can loop - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to make a calculator. The user Enters number 1, chooses and operation, enters number 2, then chooses another operation or for the answer to be displayed.

eg. 
1 + 1 =
or
1 + 1 + 2 + 1 =

Both of these should be possible.

```
read -p "what's the first number? " n1
PS3="what's the operation? "
select ans in add subtract multiply divide equals; do
case $ans in 
    add) op='+' ; break ;;
    subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
    multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
    divide) op='/' ; break ;;
    *) echo "invalid response" ;;
esac
done
read -p "what's the second number? " n2
ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
printf "%s %s %s = %s\n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2" "$ans"

exit 0
```

This is what I have written so far, but i cannot work out how to make it possible to let the user choose 'equals' or to loop back round to enter another operation. Any ideas what I can do to my code here? I have been stuck on this all day.

- I dont want the user to enter the equation themselves, i want them to be choosing from a list.

Comment: This script doesn't work at all for me. Have you copy/pasted the correct version?

Comment: read -p "what's the first number? " n1
    PS3="what's the operation? "
    select ans in add subtract multiply divide equals; do
    case $ans in 
        add) op='+' ; break ;;
        subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
        multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
        divide) op='/' ; break ;;
  equals) op=
        *) echo "invalid response" ;;
    esac
 done
    read -p "what's the second number? " n2
    ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
    printf "%s %s %s = %s\n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2" "$ans"

    exit 0

Comment: Yep @svnpenn is right duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have to put a loop around that code so it reads a number then selects an operation repeatedly. Build up the formula. When the user selects "equals", break out of the outer loop and evaluate the formula. In pseudo-ish code:

```
formula=""
while true; do
  get a number
  formula+="$number"
  select an operation
    case $op in
    ...
    equals) break 2 ;; # need to break out of 2 levels, the select and the while
    esac
  done
  formula+="$op"
done
ans=$(bc -l <<< "$formula")
printf "%s = %s\n" "$formula" "$ans"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would let the user enter the whole equation in one read. eg

```
read -p "enter equation" equate
ans=$(bc -l <<< "${equate%%=*})"
echo ${equate%%=*} = $ans
```

the <<< is a here string, the contents of the string are fed to cmd as stdin.

the %%=* in the equate variable strips of any thing after a = that may have been put in.

Comment: I would use that method, however i want to limit what they are able to input using case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "what's the first number? " n1
PS3="what's the operation? "
select ans in add subtract multiply divide equals; do
case $ans in 
    add) op='+' ; break ;;
    subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
    multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
    divide) op='/' ; break ;;
    *) echo "invalid response" ;;
esac
done
read -p "what's the second number? " n2
ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
printf "%s %s %s = %s\n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2" "$ans"

exit 0
```